Livewire radio buttons value gets overwritten? (with testable demo)
When i have a mini multistep form the radio button value of step 2 is overwriting the value of step 1. See code below.

The component
<?php
// app/Livewire/Counter.php
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Counter extends Component
{
    public $count = 1;
    public $one;
    public $two;

    public function increment()
    {
        $this->count++;
    }

    public function decrement()
    {
        $this->count--;
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.counter');
    }
}


The view
<div>
    <div class="p-10">
        <button wire:click="decrement" class="bg-green-500 p-4">-</button>
        <button wire:click="increment" class="bg-green-500 p-4">+</button>

        <h1>Count: {{ $count }}</h1>

        <br>

        @if ($count == 1)
            <input type="radio" name="page1" wire:model.live="one" value="1">
            <input type="radio" name="page1" wire:model.live="one" value="2">
            <input type="radio" name="page1" wire:model.live="one" value="3">
        @elseif($count == 2)
            <input type="radio" name="page2" wire:model.live="two" value="1">
            <input type="radio" name="page2" wire:model.live="two" value="2">
            <input type="radio" name="page2" wire:model.live="two" value="3">
        @endif

        <br>

        <p>Page one: {{ $one }}</p>
        <p>Page two: {{ $two }}</p>
    </div>
</div>


Layout
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        <livewire:counter />
    </body>
</html>



Livewire version v3.5.9
Laravel version v11.26.0
PHP 8.2

Steps To Reproduce

Create component with below details.
Choose a value for radio button
Confirm the answer is displayed on screen
Go to next step with + button
Choose another value for the second set of radio buttons
Confirm the answer is displayed on screen

What I expect:
The radio buttons on page one and page two should work independently
What I actually get:
The radio button value of step one is overwritten as soon as I pick a value in step two
Live testable demo: https://wirebox.app/b/4oedw

Give them different names in the different pages. Having them all have name="page1" means they share a single selection.

Sorry, they have different names, I used an older version here in my question. They actually have different names as it is reflected now in my question. Any ideas still? @ceejayoz

@oelimoe sorry, I just made it public

i found whats wrong it has mostly to do with the dissapearing of the input fields. i belive this can cause it to search for the next valid value the fix that i found was with using class="hidden" so it doesnt dissapear
     <div class="@if ($count != 1) hidden @endif">
        <input type="radio" name="page1" wire:model.live="one" value="1">
        <input type="radio" name="page1" wire:model.live="one" value="2">
        <input type="radio" name="page1" wire:model.live="one" value="3">
    </div>
    <div class="@if ($count != 2) hidden @endif">
        <input type="radio" name="page2" wire:model.live="two" value="4">
        <input type="radio" name="page2" wire:model.live="two" value="5">
        <input type="radio" name="page2" wire:model.live="two" value="6">
    </div>

or
this is another solution i found but its realy wierd and i dont uderstand why it works. It looks like it doesnt seperate the radios on thier name but for all of them that are currently on the page also the solotion for this one is  to give them all unique ids
    @if ($count == 1)
        <input id="1" type="radio" name="random" wire:model.live="one" value="1">
        <input id="2" type="radio" name="page1" wire:model.live="one" value="2">
        <input id="3" type="radio" name="page1" wire:model.live="one" value="3">
    @elseif($count == 2)
        <input id="4" type="radio" name="page2" wire:model.live="two" value="4">
        <input id="5" type="radio" name="page2" wire:model.live="two" value="5">
        <input id="6" type="radio" name="page2" wire:model.live="two" value="6">
    @endif


Thanks for your answer! This issue is actually a simple representation of a larger one. In the actual app I want to have a 10 step multi page/step form. Is this the only en best way to achieve this? I feels kinda "weird". Don't get me wrong, I appreciate your effort though!

i dont know if you get a notification if answer is edited so i still comment but i found something new which makes it alot wierder

Thanks. I just got a reply on discord which solves it the Livewire way by using wire:key. I think its kinda the same as ginging it unique id's. Thanks for the help again.

The Livewire solution is to add wire:key to the inputs. Like so:
@if ($count == 1)
            <input type="radio" name="page1" wire:key="page1-1" wire:model.live="one" value="1">
            <input type="radio" name="page1" wire:key="page1-2" wire:model.live="one" value="2">
            <input type="radio" name="page1" wire:key="page1-3" wire:model.live="one" value="3">
        @elseif($count == 2)
            <input type="radio" name="page2" wire:key="page2-1" wire:model.live="two" value="1">
            <input type="radio" name="page2" wire:key="page2-2" wire:model.live="two" value="2">
            <input type="radio" name="page2" wire:key="page2-3" wire:model.live="two" value="3">
        @endif

Credits to Josh Hanley on the livewire discord who said: Livewire doesn’t know that you’ve changed the inputs without help. So you need to use wire:key on each of the inputs inside the conditionals to tell livewire that they are different.
